# No <context-param> or <init-param> provided for federation

Tags: java, tomcat, struts-1

I am getting No  or  provided for federation during runtime in tomcat. I googled and did not see anything about this particular error. i know context-param and init-param should be in web.xml, but i am not sure what federation means.i am using tomcat7, struts, and java 8,

```
message No <context-param> or <init-param> provided for federation

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

com.peregrine.gt.clients.framework.ClientServletException: No <context-param> or <init-param> provided for federation
    com.peregrine.gt.clients.framework.struts.ClientServlet.initApplication(ClientServlet.java:92)
    com.peregrine.gt.clients.framework.struts.ClientServlet.init(ClientServlet.java:64)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
```

struts-config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <data-sources />
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="DirectoryExplorerForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.DirectoryExplorerForm" />
        <form-bean name="FileManagerForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.FileManagerForm" />
        <form-bean name="JobStatusForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.JobStatusForm" />
        <form-bean name="LoginForm"
            type="com.peregrine.gt.clients.framework.forms.ClientLoginForm" />
        <form-bean name="LogoutForm"
            type="com.peregrine.gt.clients.framework.forms.ClientLogoutForm" />
        <form-bean name="MonitorForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.MonitorForm" />
        <form-bean name="PrdsForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.PrdsForm" />
        <form-bean name="ProfileSyncForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.ProfileSyncForm" />
        <form-bean name="ProfileTransformerForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.ProfileTransformerForm" />
        <form-bean name="ScheduleCorpForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.ScheduleCorpForm" />
        <form-bean name="UserForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.UserForm" />
        <form-bean name="JobDisplayForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.JobDisplayForm" />  
        <form-bean name="GDSExtractForm"
            type="com.amex.travelbahn.dataservices.console.forms.GDSExtractForm" />
    </form-beans>
```

pom.xml, not all of it but most of the important jar files

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>toplink</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: mmh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482484/null-pointer-exception-in-imported-file

Comment: that was when i ran in tomcat 8. i dropped the same war file into tomcat 7 and am getting no init context

Comment: I am not sure about what `federation` is but if i google for `set <context-param> or <init-param>  for federation` the first result is your question, followed by some sites like http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.1.0/com.ibm.p8.installingcfs.doc/cfsin081.htm or https://wiki.ca.com/display/sm1252sp1/Set+Up+JBOSS+or+Tomcat+to+Work+with+Federation+Web+Services which could be of interest for you ;)

Comment: Is this struts1 or struts2, looking at config file it is struts1 but as per your tags it says struts2